# Mysql changing column from 'allow null' to 'not null' and setting value

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, default-value, alter

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `product_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES (1, 1), (2,2), (3, NULL);
```

I want to change definition of column `category_id` to forbid NULL values and make value 1 as default value.

I'm running following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `product` CHANGE `category_id` `category_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Table `product` containts next values (after successful alter query):

```
1 1
2 2
3 0
```

Desired result:

```
1 1 
2 2
3 1
```

FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is set to 1 and doesn't change.

Could someone explain why 0 is being set instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats why the undefined value for an `unsigned int` is zero. The default value is only used at `insert`statement.

Comment: So, you mean that alter statement ignores foreign key constraint and sets undefined value, hence breaking consistency?

Comment: @Mihai, foreign key constraint `product_category`. `category` has only 1 and 2, so enforcing `product` to have only two value 1 and 2. But after alter statement 0 values appears.